# Getting CKA_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT while importing certificate using swift and Safenet sdk(Programmatically)

Tags: swift, encoding, x509certificate, smartcard

I am trying to import certificate in safenet dongle using swift and safenet's sdk. I have used encoder and decoder from the below linked code https://github.com/filom/ASN1Decoder. My swift side code is like below :-

```
let subjectDistinguishedNameDER = ASN1DEREncoder.encodeSequence(content: cert!.subjectDistinguishedNameDER)
                    let issuerDistinguishedNameDER = ASN1DEREncoder.encodeSequence(content: cert!.issuerDistinguishedNameDER)
                    dongle.importCertificate(password:donglePin, enrollmentId: id, subject: (cert?.subjectDistinguishedName?.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString())!, issuer: issuerDistinguishedNameDER.base64EncodedString(), serialNumber: (cert?.serialNumber?.base64EncodedString())!, value: encodedData.base64EncodedString())
```

In the wrapper, I am doing below transformations

```
- (void) importCertificate:(NSString *) password enrollmentId:(NSString*)enrollmentId subject:(NSString*)subject issuer:(NSString*)issuer serialNumber:(NSString*)serialNumber value:(NSString*)value {
  Dongle* d = (Dongle*)dong;
  
  char * eId = strdup([enrollmentId UTF8String]);
  char * pass = strdup([password UTF8String]);
  char * sub = strdup([subject UTF8String]);
  char * iss = strdup([issuer UTF8String]);
  char * ser = strdup([serialNumber UTF8String]);
  char * val = strdup([value UTF8String]);
  //char *signData = (char *)[data bytes];
  std::cout << "size size: \n";
  //std::cout << size;
  std::cout << "value print: \n";
  
  d->importCertificate(pass, eId, sub, iss, ser, val);
}
```

I am using template as below

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE certificateTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS, &classCertificate, sizeof(classCertificate) },
        { CKA_TOKEN, &bTrue, sizeof(bTrue) },
        { CKA_LABEL, &labelPrivate, strlen((char *)labelPrivate) },
        { CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, &typeCertificate, sizeof(typeCertificate) },
        { CKA_SUBJECT, (CK_BYTE_PTR)&byteArraySub, (unsigned long)subLen },
        { CKA_VALUE, (CK_BYTE_PTR)&byteArrayVal, (unsigned long)valLen }
    };
```

in native side my methos is like :-

```
void Dongle::importCertificate(char *password, char* enrollmentId, char * subject, char * issuer, char * serialNumber, char * value ) {
    CK_RV rv = CKR_OK;
    
    CK_BBOOL    bFalse  = CK_FALSE;
    CK_BBOOL    bTrue   = CK_TRUE;
    CK_KEY_TYPE keyType = CKK_RSA;
    
    CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    LoadCryptoki(pkcs11_path);
    
    rv = GetFirstSlotId(&slotId);
    rv = C_OpenSession(slotId, (CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | CKF_RW_SESSION), NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR, &hSession);
    
    // We can also use Dongle::generateKeyPairUtil
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = Dongle::getPrivateKeyHandle(hSession, password, enrollmentId);
    
    
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject;
    
    std::string labelPriv = std::string("private") + enrollmentId;
    CK_UTF8CHAR * labelPrivate = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(labelPriv); //Label of private key.
    //std::string idPriv = std::string(enrollmentId);
    //CK_UTF8CHAR * idPrivate = convertToCK_UTF8CHAR(idPriv);
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  classCertificate = CKO_CERTIFICATE;
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS  typeCertificate = CKC_X_509;
    std::string sub;
    sub = subject;
    int subLen;
    CK_BYTE * byteArraySub = d::base64_decode(sub.c_str(),&subLen);
    std::string val;
    val = value;
    int valLen;
    CK_BYTE * byteArrayVal = d::base64_decode(val.c_str(),&valLen);
    std::cout << "byte array value: \n";
    
    CK_ATTRIBUTE certificateTemplate[] =
    {
        { CKA_CLASS, &classCertificate, sizeof(classCertificate) },
        { CKA_TOKEN, &bTrue, sizeof(bTrue) },
        { CKA_LABEL, &labelPrivate, strlen((char *)labelPrivate) },
        { CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, &typeCertificate, sizeof(typeCertificate) },
        { CKA_SUBJECT, (CK_BYTE_PTR)&byteArraySub, (unsigned long)subLen },
        { CKA_VALUE, (CK_BYTE_PTR)&byteArrayVal, (unsigned long)valLen }
    };
    std::cout << "length of subject \n";
    std::cout << (unsigned long)subLen;
    std::cout << "length of value \n";
    std::cout << (unsigned long)valLen;
    //CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hObject;
    rv = C_CreateObject( hSession,
                         certificateTemplate,
                         DIM(certificateTemplate),
                         &hObject );
    std::cout << "object handle code: \n";
    std::cout << rv;
    
    if (rv == CKR_OK) {
        std::cout<< "Created object handle"<< hObject<< std::endl;
    }

    
    if (hSession) {
        C_CloseSession(hSession);
        UnloadCryptoki();
    }
    
}
```

The base64 string of Subject is

```
Qz1CRCwgTz1CYW5nbGFkZXNoIENvbXB1dGVyIENvdW5jaWwsIE9VPVN1Yi1DQSwgQ049QkNDIFN1Yi1DQSBmb3IgQ2xhc3MgMCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZXMtRzM=
```

The base64 string of the Certificate is

```
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
```

For certificate import, CKA_ISSUER and CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER are not necessary, I have also tried by removing them.

In Both case, I am getting CKA_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT code.
Is there any way I can get rid of this issue?